# How documents are verified

Tags: residence-cards, identification

I have a question. How do governments, in the EU context, verify whether the documents of other EU nationals are not counterfeit? Do they call directly the issuing country or they have other practices?

I moved to Belgium and upon registering myself at the municipality, the employee took a copy of my ID card and sent it to the "Foreigners office" in Brussels. Since EU countries generally don't give other EU countries access to their databases, how do they verify that a document is indeed true? I'm not malignant but I believe that registering in an EU country with a well crafted fake ID is easy, considering that the algorithms generating the MRZ codes are not secret.

Comment: *well crafted fake ID* - yes, but getting a *well* crafted fake id is not at all easy or cheap. There are a lot of security features which are easy to confirm but very difficult to implement.

Comment: People are crafty today, and in my case the employee was not a forensic expert. He simply took the card and sent the scan to the Office des Étrangers. How has the verification been done? Idk

Comment: Literally it takes a crafty person to fake perfectly an ID. Take a person that know all the details of a certain country document, all its MRZ algorithms, and the job is done. Hence, I could register in any EU country if there wasn't any verification or common database between countries.

Comment: "know all the details of a certain country document": easier said than done.  "Since EU countries generally don't give other EU countries access to their databases": why do you think that?

Comment: When exchanging my driver's licence in the UK they have sent it over to Hungary for invalidation (and maybe to ask them whether all is good with it)

Comment: There are online resources like the [PRADO database](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/prado-start-page.html) that can help.

Comment: The Prado database gives description.

Comment: They don't need access to the other databases, all they need to do ask if the ID/passport is valid or not. The database for stolen (or lost) travel documents is accessible.

Comment: All these practices and documents developed long before electronic databases or networked computing, verification has never relied on systematically looking up each and every person's details in some reference database. Consider this: even within a country, routine or systematic look-up across different parts of the government may not be possible or legal. And what about people who come from outside the EU? Why do you think it matters?

Comment: @Relaxed I thought that within the EU they could verify more easily

Comment: @user At this point they are several years late on a system checking entries for third country (non-EU) citizens. There are certainly people in law enforcement who wish to have more data but it's easy to overestimate how systematic and technologically advanced enforcement really is. Policing EU citizens is not the highest priority. So far, the main effort in this area is to standardize and improve anti-forgery features on ID documents so that creating a "well crafted fake ID" is not so easy anymore.